# open all links on post in new tab , target="_blank"

Tags: wordpress

how can i set all links ( internals , externals , photos ) on all posts (WordPress) in new tab (target="_blank") ?
i don`t want to open menu links and other themes links in new tab ! only links on post.
functions codes or another code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your theme adds class to body, you should have post class "single-post"
then in JS - add:

```
$(".single-post a").attr("target","_blank");
```

if your theme doesn't add class to body, add this:

```
<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>
```